# Which tag (flight-test, flight-testing) should be the master and which the synonym?

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have the tag [flight-test](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-test) treated as synonym of [flight-testing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-testing) (that is thus the "master").

As a mod I am incentivised to proceed to merge them, and leave only the master.

Generally this is not an issue, but in this case I would like to have the feedback of the community, since:

- the "master" has a smaller question count (15 vs 42)
- it is more likely (I think) that a newcomer would use [flight-test](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-test)

What would you like me to do? Should we leave it as it is and merge [flight-test](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-test) into [flight-testing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-testing)? Or is the reverse preferable?

Comment: Well, if flight-testing is the master, when they type in flight-test, it will at least suggest it and I think that many people would take the suggestion even if they were intending on the shorter version initially.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **Flight-test** is a [transitive verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flight-test), as in to flight-test an airplane.
- **Flight testing** is "[a branch of aeronautical engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_test)".
- **Test flight** is the noun for such flight.

Keep the [flight-testing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-testing) tag as the master. And create a second synonym for the noun [test-flight](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/test-flight).

Answer (score 2):

I would leave [flight-testing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-testing) as the master tag. At least to me, "flight testing" is a general activity that can cover several related tasks or events, whereas "flight test" is one specific event. For example, analyzing sensor data afterwards is an important part of flight testing but it's not part of the flight test itself.

Comment: Though it may be less grammatically correct, "flight test" is also used as a noun for the general phase of development.